# Загрузка картинки из интернета на сайт

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Как сделать загрузку фото из интернета на сайт по ссылке, например на некоторых сайтах есть возможность загрузки аватара по ссылке.
 Я на одном сайте видел такую форму загрузки, но теперь не могу найти. Не могу понять в чем разница обычной формы загрузки файлов и формы загрузки из интернета по ссылке.

Comment: Смотрите в сторону curl на сервере. js и jquery тут не при чем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень простой пример как можно загрузить картинку с другого сайта на свой, но тут нужно сделать проверки на название файла, размер файла, ну и так далее.

```
<?php
  $link = "http://www.site.com/images/15.jpg";
  $file = file_get_contents($link);  
  file_put_contents(time().".jpg", $file);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо реализовать обычное текстовое поле, куда будете вставлять ссылку. На стороне сервера Вы уже эту ссылку будете подгружать.

Самый простой способ в PHP загрузить файл:

```
file_get_contents('http://example.com/image.jpg')
```

Более сложный вариант: использовать `curl`. Но тут важно понимать, что библиотеку, возможно, придётся устанавливать самому.

Comment: У вас опечатка в названии функции

Comment: А у Вас есть право исправить опечатку;-)

Answer (score -1):

`<?php
  $link = 'http://www.site.com/images/15.jpg';
  copy($link,  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/'.pathinfo($link, PATHINFO_BASENAME)))
  ?>`

Картинка будет загружена в папку "images" на вашем хостинге, а имя файла будет такое же как и на удаленном сервере: `http://ваш.сайт/images/15.jpg`